# How do I get specific records values out of a database in a ruby on rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

So I've been learning rails recently so I have very limited knowledge of it currently. I've been working on a personal project that requires me to be able to add and subtract specific values from tables I've created within a scaffold that I generated. With the knowledge that I have currently I can only get all the values from a given column by looping it like this:

```
<% @characters.each do |character| %>
  <%= character.fair %>
<% end %>
```

Instead of getting said "fair" value from each character I want to get the individual values from the rows too.

This could be the simplest problem ever possibly but it's just out of my scope for my current knowledge. Any help appreciated!

Comment: "Instead of getting said "fair" value from each character I want to get the individual values from the rows too." - what's the difference? It's the same thing, isn't it?

Comment: What other values are you trying to get? If `@characters` is an AR collection, you will have access to all columns for each instance, you will also have access to all the instance methods as well.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Sorry to make it unclear. I'm getting all the records from a column in one go. I just want a single value that I can pull from any of the rows.

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery For example: When I view what the code on my question gives it gives me: "16 14 -8 -6" on that webpage. I only want to be able to have the "-8" for example and I want to be able to do operators to it and other records like "16"

Comment: @Skyler: I think you want something like this: `fair_values = @characters.pluck(:fair)`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev This is actually an amazing starting point. I'm gonna see what I can do with this.

Comment: @Skyler try using some of these methods, it can reduce your query time for characters records -> https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html. It can be as simple as calculating the sum of fair value in characters 'sum = Character.sum(:fair)' will give you sum of fair values in character